# What should one do if he sees a question on Mi Yodeya by an atheist?

Tags: heresy

He asks a very lengthy question about emunah which reveals a misguided way of thinking. I also happen to know that the person is a public atheist. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking what halacha requires here or what site policy is?

Comment: Either or both!

Comment: Would this also be a meta question then?

Comment: You can't ask both together. Which do you want to ask in this post?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site and didn't know that it is particular. How about the site policy?

Comment: @user33308 site policy questions should be in the meta. I assume it will be migrated there. Welcome to Mi Yodeya either way

Comment: Site policy questions should be asked on [meta]. Questions on this site are for questions about Judaism.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be posted on the Meta section.

Answer (score 2):

Answer the question as thoroughly and honestly as you can.